# Python Pig Latin convertor and line/word counter

Tags: python, file, translation, counter, language-translation

I have to create a python file that prompts the user for a file path to a text document and then convert it into pig Latin and do a line/word count.

> • A function to generate the pig Latin version of a single word
>
> • A function to print line and word counts to standard output
>
> • Correct pig Latin output with identical formatting as the original text file
>
> • Correct line and word counts

I can't figure out why the pig latin is coming out wrong. My teacher said that I need another `string.strip("\n")` because it is making the words convert wrong but I have no idea where I am supposed to put that.

Also my line counter is broken. It counts but it **always says 222 lines**.

How can I make it just count the lines with words ?

```
#Step 1: User enters text file.
#Step 2: Pig Latin function rewrites file and saves as .txt.
#Step 3: Tracks how many lines and words it rewrites.


vowels = ("A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u")

# Functions

def pig_word(string):
    line = string.strip("\n")
    for word in string.split(" "):
        first_letter = word[0]
        if first_letter in vowels:
            return word + "way"     
        else:
            return word[1:] + first_letter + "ay"    

def pig_sentence(sentence):
    word_list = sentence.split(" ")
    convert = " "   
    for word in word_list:
        convert = convert + pig_word(word)    
        convert = convert + " "   
    return convert

def line_counter(s):
    line_count = 0
    for line in s:
        line_count += 1
    return line_count

def word_counter(line):
    word_count = 0
    list_of_words = line.split()
    word_count += len(list_of_words)
    return word_count




# File path conversion

text = raw_input("Enter the path of a text file: ")
file_path = open(text, "r")
out_file = open("pig_output.txt", "w")


s = file_path.read()
pig = pig_sentence(s)
out_file.write(pig+" ")
out_file.write("\n")


linecount = line_counter(s)
wordcount = word_counter(s)


file_path.close()
out_file.close()

# Results

print "\n\n\n\nTranslation finished and written to pig_output.txt"
print "A total of {} lines were translated successfully.".format(linecount)
print "A total of {} words were translated successfully.".format(wordcount)
print "\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

your first problem is here:

```
def pig_word(string):
    line = string.strip("\n")  #!!!! line is NEVER USED !!!
    for word in string.split(" "): #you want *line*.split here
```

the second issue is caused by iterating over a string, it goes through every character instead of every line like a file does:

```
>>> for i in "abcd":
...     print(i)    

a
b
c
d
```

so in your `line_counter` instead of doing:

```
for line in s:
    line_count += 1
```

you just need to do:

```
for line in s.split("\n"):
    line_count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The **first** reason why your not getting the output you want is because in your `pig_word(string)` function, you return the first word in the string when you put that `return` inside of your `for` loop. Also, your teacher was talking about taking all the lines into the function, and iterating over each line via `str.split('\n')`. `\n` represents the "new-line" character.

You can try something like this to correct that.

```
def pig_sentence(string):
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_string = ""
        for word in line.split(" "):
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                new_string += word + "way"
            else:
                new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay"
            lines.append(new_string)
    return lines
```

**The Changes Made**

- Initialized a new list `lines` that we can append to throughout the loops.
- Iterate over each line in the passed in string.
- For each line, create a new string `new_string`.
- Use your code, but instead of `return`ing we add it to `new_string`, then append `new_string` to our list of new lines, `lines`.
- *Note that this removes the need for two functions. Also note that I renamed `pig_word` to `pig_sentence`*.

---

2. The **second** error is in your function `line_counter(s)`. You are iterating over each character rather than each line. Here add that `str.split('\n')` again  to get the output you want by splitting the string into a list of lines then iterating over the list.

Here is the modified function:

```
def line_counter(s):
    line_count = 0
    for _ in s.split('\n'):
        line_count += 1
    return line_count
```

(Since there is nothing erroneous with your file i.o., I'm just going to use a string literal here for the testing.)

---

**Test**

```
paragraph = """\
Hello world
how are you
pig latin\
"""

lines = line_counter(paragraph)
words = sum([word_counter(line) for line in paragraph.split('\n')])
out = pig_sentence(paragraph)

print(lines, words, out)
```

The output is what we expect!

```
3 7 ['elloHay', 'elloHayorldway', 'owhay', 'owhayareway', 'owhayarewayouyay', 'igpay', 'igpayatinlay']
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! The counters now work but when I added the pig_sentence part to change out my two functions I receive a TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. How do I fix that error?

Comment: Which functions do you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

You are removing only the space, you need to remove all punctuation as well as end of line characters. Replace

```
split(" ")
```

with

```
split()
```

Your sentence list is the equivalent of

```
sentence = 'Hello there.\nMy name is Roxy.\nHow are you?
```

If you print after `split(" ")` and `split()` you will see the difference and you will get the results that you expect.

Additionally, you will get incorrect results because you will have `there` translated to `heretay`. you need to loop around so that it comes out as `erethay`

That is move every consonent to the end before adding 'ay' so that the new word starts with a vowel.